# Using correct encoding when reading from TCP/Port

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, ascii, utf-7

I'm reading a byte stream (`byte[]`) from a TCP/Port, and converting a subsection of the recieved array into a `char[]`

Assume that I am not familiar with the characteristics of the port, nor the environment on the other side of this port. All I know is that there is a port.

Part of the data that I recieve is an encoded UK Pound currency symbol (£). When I use ASCII encoding for the conversion, these symbols come through as `?`

```
var charArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(byteArray);
```

However, when I use UTF-7, all is ok:

```
var charArray = Encoding.UTF7.GetChars(byteArray);
```

I should add that when trying UTF-8, this doesn't work.

This was by trial and error, and I'm not entirely sure as to why this might have worked. Rather than just go ahead and deploy a solution, I thought I'd try to understand more as to why this might have worked.

Is it simply that the system on the other side of the port is transmitting in UTF-7, or is there something else going on?

Comment: UTf-7 can create security holes.  Try  UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't work. It doesn't give me the correct symbol

Comment: If you look at the binary data you could determine which encodings were _possiblly_ used.

Comment: As is always the case with encodings... Unless they start off with a byte order mark, there's really no way to know except pattern detection.